# Error not a valid device model name in Qemu

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I am trying to add a custom device in Qemu source code.
Below are the steps which I followed to add a device in Qemu source code:

Go to directory where qemu is installed

Then

1. created a custom device file in hw/misc/.c
2. created a entry in qemu/hw/misc/Makefile.objs
3. created a entry in qemu/config-all-devices.mak
4. created a entry in qemu/arm-softmmu/config-devices.mak
5. created a entry in qemu/arm-softmmu/config-devices.mak.old

After I run below two commands
sudo make CFLAGS="-Wno-error" 
sudo make install

Then I run qemu with my custom device
Below is the script to run qemu

```
#!/bin/bash

KERNEL="/lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-armmp-lpae"
INIT_IMAGE="/lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-armmp-lpae"
DISK="/lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32/hda30.qcow2"

/lhome/priyamvad/arm_qemu_Setup/qemu/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm \
    -M virt \
    -m 1024 \
    -smp 4 \
    -kernel $KERNEL \
    -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 \
    -device virtio-rng-device,rng=rng0 \
    -initrd $INIT_IMAGE \
    -append 'root=/dev/vda2' \
    -drive if=none,file=$DISK,format=qcow2,id=hd \
    **-device hello-world-device** \
    -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd \
    -device virtio-net-device,netdev=usernet \
    -netdev user,id=usernet,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
    -nographic
```

When I run above script, I get following error:

**ERROR**:

> qemu-system-arm: -device hello-world-device: 'hello-world-device' is
>   not a valid device model name

So what i am missing in above steps?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to edit some files which are autogenerated by the configure and make process, so when you run make your changes will be overwritten again: config-devices.mak, config-devices.mak.old and config-all-devices.mak are all autogenerated.

The place you want to put your new CONFIG_HELLO_DEVICE=y is in default-configs/arm-softmmu.mak. Then hw/misc/Makefile.objs can use it in a line like "common-obj-$(CONFIG_HELLO_DEVICE) += hello.o".

Check that your source file is actually getting compiled and linked into the QEMU binary when you run make. If it is, then the problem is something in your C sources; if it is not, then you haven't got your makefile/default-configs stuff right.

Some extra advice:

```
sudo make CFLAGS="-Wno-error" sudo make install
```

is a really bad way to do "compile QEMU for testing":

- it's running the whole make process as root unnecessarily
- it's doing an install, which you don't need to do to just run the QEMU binary you've built for testing
- you're overriding the default "warnings are errors" setting, which is just hiding bugs in your code you need to fix (and if you really do need to do this for some reason, it's the wrong way to do it: there is a configure --disable-werror option)
- it's doing a build in the source directory, which means that autogenerated files from the build get mixed in with the source files. This is why you got confused and tried to edit the autogenerated config-devices.mak files I think.

Upstream QEMU strongly recommends doing a build in a separate build directory (I give some plausible configure options but use what you want):

```
 mkdir build
 (cd build && ../configure --target-list=arm-softmmu --enable-debug)
 make -j8 -C build
```

(You will need to do a 'distclean' on your current source tree to get rid of the results of the build-in-source-tree or just throw it away and start again to get to a clean state that you can then do an out-of-tree build from.)

Once you've done 'make' you can simply run the built qemu binary directly as `./build/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm`.

Comment: Hey  @Peter Maydell I don't find a method on how to ask a question(including images,code snippets) on someone answer(like yours) on stack overflow. So ,I have asked question in the form of answer. Please reply to the question.Sorry for the mistake I did

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the method you suggested for adding custom device to Qemu(arm-32bit) source code but it give following errors:

1. Added entry for my device in following file hw/misc/Makefile.objs and default-configs/arm-softmmu.mak
2. Run make by giving below commands

   `make distclean
    make -j8 -C build`
3. I am attaching below image to show output containing error

[qemu-system-arm build error](https://github.com/PriyamvadAcharya/virtual_prototype_qemu/blob/master/Makefile.objs)

- After checking the output shown by above image, I created a file "config-devices.mak" in build/arm-softmmu.
- I once again run commands described in step 2.
- I get following output and error show below.

  **ERROR**

  ```
  ar: creating libfdt/libfdt.a
  ```

  ar: creating /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/build/capstone/libcapstone.a
  In file included from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/hw/misc/testpci.c:19:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/hw/hw.h:8:20: error: expected \u2018=\u2019, \u2018,\u2019, \u2018;\u2019, \u2018asm\u2019 or \u2018__attribute__\u2019 before \u2018hw_error\u2019
   void QEMU_NORETURN hw_error(const char *fmt, ...) GCC_FMT_ATTR(1, 2);
                      ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:7,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memory.h:19,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/hw/pci/pci.h:4,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/hw/misc/testpci.c:20:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/hwaddr.h:11:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
   typedef uint64_t hwaddr;
           ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memory.h:19,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/hw/pci/pci.h:4,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/hw/misc/testpci.c:20:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:15:28: error: unknown type name \u2018CPUState\u2019
   void tcg_flush_softmmu_tlb(CPUState *cs);
                              ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:37:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uintptr_t\u2019
   typedef uintptr_t ram_addr_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:46:60: error: unknown type name \u2018uint32_t\u2019
   typedef void CPUWriteMemoryFunc(void *opaque, hwaddr addr, uint32_t value);
                                                              ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:47:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uint32_t\u2019
   typedef uint32_t CPUReadMemoryFunc(void *opaque, hwaddr addr);
           ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:52:1: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   RAMBlock *qemu_ram_block_by_name(const char *name);
   ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:53:1: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   RAMBlock *qemu_ram_block_from_host(void *ptr, bool round_offset,
   ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:53:47: error: unknown type name \u2018bool\u2019; did you mean \u2018_Bool\u2019?
   RAMBlock *qemu_ram_block_from_host(void *ptr, bool round_offset,
                                                 ^~~~
                                                 _Bool
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:55:39: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   ram_addr_t qemu_ram_block_host_offset(RAMBlock *rb, void *host);
                                         ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:56:25: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   void qemu_ram_set_idstr(RAMBlock *block, const char *name, DeviceState *dev);
                           ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:56:60: error: unknown type name \u2018DeviceState\u2019
   void qemu_ram_set_idstr(RAMBlock *block, const char *name, DeviceState *dev);
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:57:27: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   void qemu_ram_unset_idstr(RAMBlock *block);
                             ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:58:32: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   const char *qemu_ram_get_idstr(RAMBlock *rb);
                                  ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:59:30: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   void *qemu_ram_get_host_addr(RAMBlock *rb);
                                ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:60:32: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   ram_addr_t qemu_ram_get_offset(RAMBlock *rb);
                                  ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:61:37: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   ram_addr_t qemu_ram_get_used_length(RAMBlock *rb);
                                       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:62:1: error: unknown type name \u2018bool\u2019; did you mean \u2018_Bool\u2019?
   bool qemu_ram_is_shared(RAMBlock *rb);
   ^~~~
   _Bool
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:62:25: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   bool qemu_ram_is_shared(RAMBlock *rb);
                           ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:63:1: error: unknown type name \u2018bool\u2019; did you mean \u2018_Bool\u2019?
   bool qemu_ram_is_uf_zeroable(RAMBlock *rb);
   ^~~~
   _Bool
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:63:30: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   bool qemu_ram_is_uf_zeroable(RAMBlock *rb);
                                ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:64:31: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   void qemu_ram_set_uf_zeroable(RAMBlock *rb);
                                 ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:65:1: error: unknown type name \u2018bool\u2019; did you mean \u2018_Bool\u2019?
   bool qemu_ram_is_migratable(RAMBlock *rb);
   ^~~~
   _Bool
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:65:29: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   bool qemu_ram_is_migratable(RAMBlock *rb);
                               ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:66:30: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   void qemu_ram_set_migratable(RAMBlock *rb);
                                ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:67:32: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   void qemu_ram_unset_migratable(RAMBlock *rb);
                                  ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:69:1: error: unknown type name \u2018size_t\u2019
   size_t qemu_ram_pagesize(RAMBlock *block);
   ^~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:69:1: note: \u2018size_t\u2019 is defined in header \u2018\u2019; did you forget to \u2018#include \u2019?
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:8:1:
  +#include 
   #endif
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:69:1:
   size_t qemu_ram_pagesize(RAMBlock *block);
   ^~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:69:26: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   size_t qemu_ram_pagesize(RAMBlock *block);
                            ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:70:1: error: unknown type name \u2018size_t\u2019
   size_t qemu_ram_pagesize_largest(void);
   ^~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:70:1: note: \u2018size_t\u2019 is defined in header \u2018\u2019; did you forget to \u2018#include \u2019?
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:72:42: error: unknown type name \u2018uint8_t\u2019
   void cpu_physical_memory_rw(hwaddr addr, uint8_t *buf,
                                            ^~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h: In function \u2018cpu_physical_memory_read\u2019:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:77:5: error: implicit declaration of function \u2018cpu_physical_memory_rw\u2019; did you mean \u2018cpu_physical_memory_read\u2019? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       cpu_physical_memory_rw(addr, buf, len, 0);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       cpu_physical_memory_read
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:77:5: error: nested extern declaration of \u2018cpu_physical_memory_rw\u2019 [-Werror=nested-externs]
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h: At top level:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:89:30: error: unknown type name \u2018QEMUBH\u2019; did you mean \u2018QEMU_HW_H\u2019?
   void cpu_register_map_client(QEMUBH *bh);
                                ^~~~~~
                                QEMU_HW_H
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:90:32: error: unknown type name \u2018QEMUBH\u2019; did you mean \u2018QEMU_HW_H\u2019?
   void cpu_unregister_map_client(QEMUBH *bh);
                                  ^~~~~~
                                  QEMU_HW_H
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:92:1: error: unknown type name \u2018bool\u2019; did you mean \u2018_Bool\u2019?
   bool cpu_physical_memory_is_io(hwaddr phys_addr);
   ^~~~
   _Bool
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:103:32: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   typedef int (RAMBlockIterFunc)(RAMBlock *rb, void *opaque);
                                  ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:105:28: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlockIterFunc\u2019
   int qemu_ram_foreach_block(RAMBlockIterFunc func, void *opaque);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:106:29: error: unknown type name \u2018RAMBlock\u2019
   int ram_block_discard_range(RAMBlock *rb, uint64_t start, size_t length);
                               ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:106:43: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
   int ram_block_discard_range(RAMBlock *rb, uint64_t start, size_t length);
                                             ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:106:59: error: unknown type name \u2018size_t\u2019
   int ram_block_discard_range(RAMBlock *rb, uint64_t start, size_t length);
                                                             ^~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/cpu-common.h:106:59: note: \u2018size_t\u2019 is defined in header \u2018\u2019; did you forget to \u2018#include \u2019?
  In file included from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memory.h:21,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/hw/pci/pci.h:4,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/hw/misc/testpci.c:20:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memattrs.h:69:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uint32_t\u2019
   typedef uint32_t MemTxResult;
           ^~~~~~~~
  In file included from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:4,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/host-utils.h:29,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memop.h:15,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memory.h:22,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/hw/pci/pci.h:4,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/hw/misc/testpci.c:20:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:87:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uint8_t\u2019
   typedef uint8_t flag;
           ^~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:93:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   typedef uint16_t float16;
           ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:94:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uint32_t\u2019
   typedef uint32_t float32;
           ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:95:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
   typedef uint64_t float64;
           ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:106:5: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
       uint64_t low;
       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:107:5: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
       uint16_t high;
       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:115:5: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
       uint64_t low, high;
       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/fpu/softfloat-types.h:169:5: error: unknown type name \u2018uint8_t\u2019
       uint8_t     float_exception_flags;
       ^~~~~~~
  In file included from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/host-utils.h:29,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memop.h:15,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/exec/memory.h:22,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/hw/pci/pci.h:4,
                   from /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/hw/misc/testpci.c:20:
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:29:15: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   static inline uint16_t bswap16(uint16_t x)
                 ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:29:32: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   static inline uint16_t bswap16(uint16_t x)
                                  ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:35:15: error: unknown type name \u2018uint32_t\u2019
   static inline uint32_t bswap32(uint32_t x)
                 ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:35:32: error: unknown type name \u2018uint32_t\u2019
   static inline uint32_t bswap32(uint32_t x)
                                  ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:43:15: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
   static inline uint64_t bswap64(uint64_t x)
                 ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:43:32: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
   static inline uint64_t bswap64(uint64_t x)
                                  ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:56:29: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   static inline void bswap16s(uint16_t *s)
                               ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:61:29: error: unknown type name \u2018uint32_t\u2019
   static inline void bswap32s(uint32_t *s)
                               ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:66:29: error: unknown type name \u2018uint64_t\u2019
   static inline void bswap64s(uint64_t *s)
                               ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:21: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
                       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:142:15: note: in definition of macro \u2018CPU_CONVERT\u2019
   static inline type endian ## size ## _to_cpu(type v)\
                 ^~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:21: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
                       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:142:46: note: in definition of macro \u2018CPU_CONVERT\u2019
   static inline type endian ## size ## _to_cpu(type v)\
                                                ^~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:21: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
                       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:147:15: note: in definition of macro \u2018CPU_CONVERT\u2019
   static inline type cpu_to_ ## endian ## size(type v)\
                 ^~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:21: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
                       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:147:46: note: in definition of macro \u2018CPU_CONVERT\u2019
   static inline type cpu_to_ ## endian ## size(type v)\
                                                ^~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:21: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
                       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:152:47: note: in definition of macro \u2018CPU_CONVERT\u2019
   static inline void endian ## size ## _to_cpus(type *p)\
                                                 ^~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:21: error: unknown type name \u2018uint16_t\u2019
   CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
                       ^~~~~~~~
  /lhome/priyamvad/debian_qemu_arm32_updated/qemu/include/qemu/bswap.h:157:51: note: in definition of macro \u2018CPU_CONVERT\u2019
   static inline void cpu_to_ ## endian ## size ## s(type *p)\
- **Are the above errors due to bugs in qemu source code or I am doing something nasty?**

> > > Some description about my work
> > >
> > > - Creating a custom device in Qemu.
> > > - Creating a device driver to test custom device.
> >
> > - I have created custom device and now I want to run my custom device on Qemu
> > - Qemu is imitating ARM(32 bit) hardware and running debian on it.
>
> - **Is it necessary to create device driver for custom device or it can be tested by a user application ?**
>
> Code of files used

**custom device source file**
[custom device](https://github.com/PriyamvadAcharya/virtual_prototype_qemu/blob/master/testpci.c)

**Makefile.objs source file**
[Makefile.objs](https://github.com/PriyamvadAcharya/virtual_prototype_qemu/blob/master/Makefile.objs)

**config-device.mak souce file**
[config-device.mak](https://github.com/PriyamvadAcharya/virtual_prototype_qemu/blob/master/config-devices_backup.mak)

Comment: Stop writing custom config-device.mak files! They are *autogenerated*!

Comment: Your actual compile error is because you have not put #include "qemu/osdep.h" as the first include of your source file. This is a mandatory rule for all QEMU .c files.

Comment: Hey Peter, I have included "qemu/osdep.h" as first include of source file but still same error persists .

Comment: I have following includes in my source file sequentially 1) "qemu/osdep.h",2) "qemu/units.h",3) "hw/pci/pci.h",4) "qemu/module.h". Are the following header files necessary or I am missing any header files which should be necessary?